# Override base less property UI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Is there a way to override somehow base property that comes from

https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/themes/base/Token.less

I need to change

`@_sap_m_Token_Sys_Cancel_Icon: true;`

to false, but of course not in the UI5 library itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override it this way

```js
  var parameters_get = Parameters.get;

  Parameters.get = function(N, k) {
    if (N === "_sap_m_Token_Sys_Cancel_Icon") {
      return false;
    }
    return parameters_get(N, k);
  }
```

sample: https://jsbin.com/bomosaz/edit?js,output